# create density plots of continuous field by categorical field

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the code below which overlays a density curve on a histogram.  It does this  for the ‘Fresh’ field in my data, which is a continuous field.  I would like to create similar plots filtering by the unique values in the ‘Channel’ field.  For example in pandas to create histograms similar to what I'm trying to accomplish I would use:

```
data_df.hist(column=‘Fresh’,by=‘Channel’)
```

Can anyone suggest how to do something similar for the seaborn code below?

code:

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.distplot(data_df[‘Fresh’], hist=True, kde=True, 
                             bins=int(data_df.shape[0]/5), color = 'darkblue', 
                             hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'},
                             kde_kws={'linewidth': 4})
```

data

```
  Channel  Fresh
0        2  12669
1        2   7057
2        2   6353
3        1  13265
4        2  22615
5        2   9413
6        2  12126
7        2   7579
8        1   5963
9        2   6006
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the Seaborn way is to create a `FacetGrid`, and then to `map` an axis-level plotting function onto it. In your case:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(data_df, col='Channel', margin_titles=True)
g.map(sns.distplot, 
      'Fresh',
      bins=int(data_df.shape[0]/5),
      color='darkblue', 
      hist_kws={'edgecolor': 'black'},
      kde_kws={'linewidth': 4});
```

[image: Histograms with KDEs faceted using sns.FacetGrid]

Check out the docs for more: https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/axis_grids.html

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can `groupby` your DataFrame based on the `Channel` and then plot the two groups in different subplots

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data_df = pd.DataFrame({'Channel': [2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
                        'Fresh': [12669,  7057,  6353, 13265, 22615,  
                                  9413, 12126,  7579,  5963,6006]})
df1 = data_df.groupby('Channel')

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=len(df1), figsize=(10, 3))

for ax, df in zip(axes.flatten(), df1.groups):
    sns.distplot(df1.get_group(df)['Fresh'], hist=True, kde=True, 
                             bins=int(data_df.shape[0]/5), color = 'darkblue', 
                             hist_kws={'edgecolor':'black'},
                             kde_kws={'linewidth': 4}, ax=ax)

plt.tight_layout()
```

[image]